# Lenght of the curve from origin to..

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate an integral whose value is the length of the segment of the curve ($t^2/2,(4/3) t^{3/2},2t$) from the origin to the point ($1/2,4/3,2$). Fairly simple problem but I am stuck after taking the integral of the curve. Any help would be great.

Comment: It would help if you showed a little more of what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: After taking the integral is where I am pretty much stuck at. Don't know how to appraoch the problem after that.

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the integral"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the usual formula for arclength. The derivatives are $t$, $2t^{1/2}$, and $2$. The sum of their squares is $t^2+4t+4$. You need to integrate the square root of this from $t=0$ to $t=1$. The square root is $t+2$.

Calculating $\int_0^1(t+2)\,dt$ is straightforward.

Comment: So you take the magnitude of the curve, evaluate it from 0 to 1, and just add the point to the curve?

Comment: I thought you wanted the arclength. You do not add it to anything. It is the answer to the question.

Comment: Right, I did reach the step where you concluded but what I was confuused about was where it says "to the point." What does that mean here?

Comment: That tells you to integrate to $t=1$.

Comment: I guess studying up till 2 AM is really getting to me but I am not seeing how t=1 came from the point. Could you explain that part?

Comment: Sorry for the time delay (sleep!). The given point $(1.2,4/3,2)$ is obtained by putting $t=1$ in the general parametric equation. Just put $t=1$ in the expression. In the same way, the origin is obtainind by putting $t=0$ in the equation. That's why we integrate from $t=0$ to $t=1$.